# Export to Excel - JSP Page

Tags: jsp, html-table, export-to-excel

I have a simple table which I would like to export to an Excel file on click of a button.

I wrote a function in JavaScript, but I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
function CreateExcelSheet()
{
    var x=myTable.rows
    var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
    xls.visible = true
    xls.Workbooks.Add
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        var y = x[i].cells
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
        {
            xls.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = y[j].innerText
        }
    }
}
```

This is the button on the JSP page:

```
</table>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateExcelSheet()" value="Export"></input>
</form>
```

It used to work earlier but it is not working now. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that ActiveX works in MSIE only, not in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">

function runApp()
{
    var x=myTable.rows;
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.visible = true;
    var Book = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        var y = x[i].cells;
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++)
        {
            Book.ActiveSheet.Cells( i+1, j+1).Value = y[j].innerText;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). This is one example.

[http://www.koders.com/java/fid8624B82721FCB1B8C982E6BA5D17D2C7DD87D09C.aspx?s=HSSF+main+excel#L19](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8624B82721FCB1B8C982E6BA5D17D2C7DD87D09C.aspx?s=HSSF%20main%20excel#L19)

It creates "Workbook" , then inside a method called make2 it creates a "Sheet" and add the rows and cells. The values of the cells are passed to the method as Vector.

Another option is that you can use [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/). The display tag has a feature that allow the user to export the html table to excel file.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple alternative is to call a servlet, that servlet returns an xls created from html table tags (this is suitable for really simple tables for complex ones you might want to use POI). From this [CodeRanch resource](http://www.coderanch.com/t/363613/Servlets/java/import-HTML-rows-Excel).

in your jsp you have this:

> <form method="post"
>   action="DownloadAsExcel"> <input
>   type="submit" name="submit" value="Download
>   as Excel" /> </form>

in your backend :

```
public class DownloadAsExcel extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr bgcolor=lightblue><td>Hello </td><td>James</td></tr>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not fool Excel with a HTML table with the wrong content type. This will finally end up in trouble in all colors. Rather return a real XLS file or just a CSV file.